# ResultSet Data of every row store in other array index

Tags: java, resultset

I am new in JAVA, so kindly understand my question and please give your valuable and precise answer.

How to store resultset data in anohter array ? Should I use ArrayList etc. My code is just for example.

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet query_rs;
String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
query_rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int counter_rs = 0;
ArrayList my_arr = new ArrayList();
while(query_rs.next())
{
  //here I want to add one row data in array index
  counter_rs++;  
  my_arr[counter_rs] = query_rs;  //Store row data in particular array index
}

System.out.println(my_arr.toString()); //Show all data
```

P.S. My major line is `my_arr[counter_rs] = query_rs;`. Thanks in advance

Comment: "kindly understand my question" - No question.

Comment: It's really not clear what your problem is. Does your code currently work? If not, what's the error? If so, what's the question exactly?

Comment: Why don't you get NPE here `query_rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_arr` is arraylist if you want to add any element `my_arr.add(anyElement)` or if you want to set any element in particular location use this `set(int index, E element)`

```
my_arr.set(0,anyElement);


Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet query_rs;
String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
query_rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int counter_rs = 0;
ArrayList my_arr = new ArrayList();
while(query_rs.next())
{
  //here I want to add one row data in array index    
  my_arr.set(counter_rs,query_rs); //use this
  // or
  //  my_arr.add(query_rs);
  counter_rs++; 

}

//System.out.println(my_arr.toString()); //Show all data
// use for loop to get all data
```

Comment: How can I show or print what my_arr have ? If I use this System.out.println(my_arr); ... It shows "[com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@6ddbe530, com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@6ddbe530" .. Do you have any other option ?

Comment: you can get values by while loop, this is very simple example [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) 
`rs.getString(1);` where `getString`is method which gets String column from database and `1`(which is parameter) is column position suppose your DB has 2 column named `id` and `name` then we will use `rs.getString(1);` and `rs.getString(2);` `1`=`id` and `2`=`name` you can also pass column actual name writen in DB like so `rs.getInt("id");` and rs.getString("name");

Answer (score 1):

`my_arr` is [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) not array

```
ArrayList my_arr = new ArrayList();
```

use `my_arr.add()` not as  `my_arr[counter_rs] = query_rs;`

Comment: When I print this. It shows like "[[Ljava.lang.Object;@50cedf4e, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3da6a354, [Ljava.lang.Object;@72cff6b, [Ljava.lang"

Comment: @GoogleUser don't make it toString just use System.out.println(my_arr);

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question, then i think you need to do the following:

First declare an arrayList with a RowType like >

```
ArrayList<DataRow> my_arr = new ArrayList<DataRow>(); // DataRow should hold the columns data.
```

Second : add each fetched row to the list.

```
while(query_rs.next())
{
   DataRow row = // fill the row from the ResultSet
   my_arr.add(row);
}
```

third : loop over the list and print the data;